# ¿Cómo funciona el algoritmo MonteCarlo cuando todos los movimientos posibles parecen haberse agotado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, búsqueda-monte-carlo

Intenté aplicar el algoritmo de Monte Carlo a árboles binarios, aqui esta la estructura del arbol que construyo de una manera grafica :

```
               10
             /    \
            6      14
           / \    /  \
          5   8  11  18
```

Pero tenía dudas sobre la construcción del algoritmo, que proviene de mi professor, cuando se acaba el ciclo sobre los posibles desplazamientos. Aqui esta el agloritmo MonteCarlo de mi professor que traduje de C ++ a Python

```
def playout(board):
    '''from Tristan Cazenave's algorithm'''
    moves = np.zeros(2)# shoudln't we get them from the board ?
    while(True):
        nb,moves = board.legalMoves(moves)
        if((nb == 0) or board.terminal()):
            return board.score()
        n = random.randint(0, nb) # chose a number between 0 and the number of legal moves
        board.play(moves[n]) # play a random move
        if(board.length >= MaxPlayoutLength -20):
            return 0

def nested(board, n):
    '''Nested Monte Carlo algorithm
    a general name for a broad class of algorithms that use random sampling to obtain numerical results.
    It is used to solve statistical problems by simulation.'''

    nbMoves = 0
    moves = np.zeros(2)

    lengthBestRollout[n] -1
    scoreBestRollout[n] - DBL_MAX
    res = -DBL_MAX
    while(True):
        # we test wether we reached the bottom of the tree
        if(board.terminal()):
            return 0.0 # but why should it be 0.0 ?
        # we get the number of moves and moves we can go from the selected nodes
        nbMoves,moves = board.legalMoves(moves)
        # ???
        for i in range(0,nbMoves):
            moves = list(filter (lambda a: a != 0.0, moves))
            print("moves : ")
            print(moves)
            b = board
            b.play(moves[i])
            if(n==1):
                playout(board)
            else:
                nested (board, n-1)
            score = board.score()
            if(score > scoreBestRollout [n]):
                scoreBestRollout [n] = score
                lengthBestRollout [n] = board.length
                for k in range(0,board.length):
                    bestRollout[n][k]=board.rollout[k]
                if(n>3):
                    for i in range(0,t<n-1):
                        print("n =", n,"progress =", board.length, "score =", scoreBestRollout [n])
                        depth = 0
                        # board.print(stderr) # what 
                        print("")
                        bestBoard = board
                if ((n > 1) and (score > bestScoreNested)):
                    bestScoreNested = score
                    print("best score = ", score)
                    print("")
                    bestBoard = board
        print("nbMoves = ",nbMoves,"so we're going to play", bestRollout[n][board.length])
        board.play(bestRollout[n][board.length])
        #board.play(5)
        print()
    return 0.0
```

Utilisa `bestRollout [n] [board.length]` Pero creo que no entendí para qué sirve para elegir el proximo nodo. Para mí, no pondría esta última línea y habría devuelto el puntaje, pero es parte del código C ++ de mi profesor, así que tengo dudas.mont

Pueden obtenerlo [sobre GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/NestedMonteCarloForBinaryTrees/blob/master/main.py) pero aqui esta el entero algoritmo con las clases `Node`, `Tree` y `Board` :

```
# Attempt to apply a Nested Monte Carlo Algorithm to binary trees

import random
from random import randint
import numpy as np

MaxPlayoutLength = 20 # what ?

# Class for construct the nodes of the tree. (Subtrees)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, parent_node = None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key
        if parent_node == None:
            self.parent = self
        else:
            self.parent = parent_node

# Class with the  structure of the tree. 
# I'm not sure if this Tree is balanced.
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    # Insert a single element
    def insert(self, x):
        if(self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(x)
        else:
            self._insert(x, self.root)

    # place it at the right palce
    def _insert(self, x, node):
        if(x < node.key):
            if(node.left == None):
                node.left = Node(x, node)
            else:
                self._insert(x, node.left)
        else:
            if(node.right == None):
                node.right = Node(x, node)
            else:
                self._insert(x, node.right)

    # Given a element, return a node in the tree with key x. 
    def find(self, x):
        if(self.root == None):
            return None
        else:
            return self._find(x, self.root)

    def _find(self, x, node):
        if(x == node.key):
            return node
        elif(x < node.key):
            if(node.left == None):
                return None
            else:
                return self._find(x, node.left)
        elif(x > node.key):
            if(node.right == None):
                return None
            else:
                return self._find(x, node.right)

    # Given a node, return the node in the tree with the next largest element.
    def next(self, node):
        if node.right != None:
            return self._left_descendant(node.right)
        else:
            return self._right_ancestor(node)

    def _left_descendant(self, node):
        if node.left == None:
            return node
        else:
            return self._left_descendant(node.left)

    def _right_ancestor(self, node):
        if node.key <= node.parent.key:
            return node.parent
        else:
            return self._right_ancestor(node.parent)

    # Delete an element of the tree
    def delete(self, x):
        node = self.find(x)
        if node == None:
            print(x, "isn't in the tree")
        else:
            if node.right == None:
                if node.left == None:
                    if node.key < node.parent.key:
                        node.parent.left = None
                        del node # Clean garbage
                    else:
                        node.parent.right = None
                        del Node # Clean garbage
                else:
                    node.key = node.left.key
                    node.left = None
            else:
                x = self.next(node)
                node.key = x.key
                x = None

# a tree with a selected node at a given time
class Board:
    '''a Board is a tree with a node selected which gives a score'''
    def __init__(self, btree):
        self.tree = btree
        self.root = btree.root
        self.root.left = btree.root.left
        self.root.right = btree.root.right
        self.length = 0 # length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

        print("Board initialized")
        print("root :")
        print(self.root.key)

        if(btree.root.left is not None):
            print("btree.root.left.key")
            print(btree.root.left.key)

        if(btree.root.right is not None):
            print("btree.root.right.key")
            print(btree.root.right.key)



        moves = np.zeros(2) 
        if(btree.root.left != None):
            self.moves[0] = btree.root.left 
            self.moves[1] = btree.root.right
            score = btree.root.key

    def legalMoves(self, moves):
        '''Assign the number of legal moves from root and gives the number of legal Moves'''
        numberLegal = 0

        # we assign the array of possible moves
        if(self.root.left is not None):
            moves[0] = self.root.left.key
        if(self.root.right is not None):
            moves[1] = self.root.right.key

        # we get the number of legalMoves
        for i in range(0,len(moves)):
            if(moves[i] != 0):
                numberLegal = numberLegal+1

        # and we give back the number of possible moves and the moves theselves
        return numberLegal, moves

    def terminal(self):
        '''Test wether we reached the end of a branch of a tree'''
        if((self.root.left == None) and (self.root.right  == None)):
            print("board terminal")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def score(self):
        '''Gives the value of the root'''
        return self.root.key

    def play(self,key):
        '''chose the next node we dive into, if legal :
        - node : next node the player wants to dive into
        '''
        # no test for the moment, let's see if it can make it
        node = self.tree.find(key)
        print("key we try to play",key)
        if(node is not None):
            self.root = node
            self.root.left = node.left
            self.root.right = node.right
            print("BOARD HAS CHANGED")
        else:
            print("Trying to play a key which doesn't belong to the tree")
            print(key)

        # length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

def playout(board):
    '''from Tristan Cazenave's algorithm'''
    moves = np.zeros(2)# shoudln't we get them from the board ?
    while(True):
        nb,moves = board.legalMoves(moves)
        if((nb == 0) or board.terminal()):
            return board.score()
        print("nb",nb)
        n = random.randint(0, nb) # chose a number between 0 and the number of legal moves
        board.play(moves[n]) # play a random move
        if(board.length >= MaxPlayoutLength -20):
            return 0

bestScoreNested = -9999
DBL_MAX = -9999

arraySize = 10

lengthBestRollout = np.zeros(10) # array of size 10
scoreBestRollout = np.zeros(10) # array of size 10

bestRollout =np.zeros((10,MaxPlayoutLength)) # 2 dimensional array of size 10*MaxPlayoutLength

def nested(board, n):
    '''Nested Monte Carlo algorithm
    a general name for a broad class of algorithms that use random sampling to obtain numerical results.
    It is used to solve statistical problems by simulation.'''

    nbMoves = 0
    moves = np.zeros(2)

    lengthBestRollout[n] -1
    scoreBestRollout[n] - DBL_MAX
    res = -DBL_MAX
    while(True):
        # we test wether we reached the bottom of the tree
        if(board.terminal()):
            return 0.0 # but why should it be 0.0 ?
        # we get the number of moves and moves we can go from the selected nodes
        nbMoves,moves = board.legalMoves(moves)
        # ???
        for i in range(0,nbMoves): # what ???? If I have one move we turn two times ???
            moves = list(filter (lambda a: a != 0.0, moves))
            print("moves : ")
            print(moves)
            b = board
            b.play(moves[i])
            if(n==1):
                playout(board)
            else:
                nested (board, n-1)
            score = board.score()
            if(score > scoreBestRollout [n]):
                scoreBestRollout [n] = score
                lengthBestRollout [n] = board.length
                for k in range(0,board.length):
                    bestRollout[n][k]=board.rollout[k]
                if(n>3):
                    for i in range(0,t<n-1):
                        print("n =", n,"progress =", board.length, "score =", scoreBestRollout [n])
                        depth = 0
                        # board.print(stderr) # what 
                        print("")
                        bestBoard = board
                if ((n > 1) and (score > bestScoreNested)):
                    bestScoreNested = score
                    print("best score = ", score)
                    print("")
                    bestBoard = board
        print("nbMoves = ",nbMoves,"so we're going to play", bestRollout[n][board.length])
        board.play(bestRollout[n][board.length])
        #board.play(5)
        print()
    return 0.0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tests
    t = Tree()
    t.insert(5)
    t.insert(6)
    t.insert(8)
    t.insert(10)
    t.insert(11)
    t.insert(14)
    t.insert(18)

    b = Board(t)

    score = nested(b,3)
    print("the algorithm score is ",score)

    # Remember: Find method return the node object. 
    # To return a number use t.find(nº).key
    # But it will cause an error if the number is not in the tree.
```

Aqui esta lo que me contesta el terminal al compilar er codigo :

> ```
> Board initialized
> root :
> 5
> btree.root.right.key
> 6
> moves : 
> [6.0]
> key we try to play 6.0
> BOARD HAS CHANGED
> moves : 
> [8.0]
> key we try to play 8.0
> BOARD HAS CHANGED
> moves : 
> [10.0]
> key we try to play 10.0
> BOARD HAS CHANGED
> key we try to play 0.0
> Trying to play a key which doesn't belong to the tree
> 0.0
> nbMoves =  1 so we're going to play 0.0
> key we try to play 0.0
> Trying to play a key which doesn't belong to the tree
> 0.0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 273, in <module>
>     score = nested(b,3)
>   File "main.py", line 235, in nested
>     nested (board, n-1)
>   File "main.py", line 235, in nested
>     nested (board, n-1)
>   File "main.py", line 224, in nested
>     nbMoves,moves = board.legalMoves(moves)
>   File "main.py", line 146, in legalMoves
>     moves[1] = self.root.right.key
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range
> ```

Comment: Creo que tu profesor quiere enseñar demasiado en muy poco tiempo, una cosa son arboles binarios y otra cosa muy distinta el algoritmo de montecarlo. Por lo que entiendo quiere llenar un arbolo binario con números obtenidos de una simulación de montecarlo. Creo deberías estudiar arboles binarios(estructuras de datos) por un lado y por otro la simulación montecarlo (investigación de operaciones->simulación de sistemas). La duda que preguntas de desplazamientos parece mas tema de arboles que de montecarlo. Aunque parezca que soy ignorante pero nunca había oído de estos temas juntos.

Comment: @abrahamhs Mi profesor escribió [un artículo](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~cazenave/papers/nested.pdf) muy citado cuyos párrafos tres y cuatro se refieren directamente a este tipo de simulaciones sobre arboles binarios

Comment: Por ahí hubieras empezado, en un tema en un articulo difícilmente vas a encontrar ayuda en un foro porque generalmente son temas muy recientes, incluso son nuevos descubrimientos, ademas que la mayoría son temas de postgrados que no cualquiera maneja. Te comento que he empezado a estudiar el algoritmo, pero posiblemente me tarde mas que tu en entenderlo. Ahora no he terminado de leerlo pero creo que estas confundido. Lo del arbol (por lo que he leído) es una explicación de como se desenvuelve el algoritmo en la memoria de la computadora, pero no veo que tengas que programar un árbol.

Comment: porque no pones el código c++ de tu profesor??